# What should i include in this while loop to satisfy the requirements

Tags: javascript, while-loop

### Requirements:

> Create a program that uses a while loop to simulate playing a
> multi-level game. In the “game,” there are NUM_LEVELS levels. Each
> loop iteration will simulate playing one level of the game. At the end
> of each loop, the player will level up. The “game” will end once the
> player has completed all of the levels.
>
> Create a variable called level to keep track of which level the player
> is on. Create a function for each level called playLevel# (e.g.
> playLevel3) that prints a description of that level to the console.
> You should have three functions in all: playLevel1, playLevel2, and
> playLevel3. Use a while loop to “play” a level and level up. Your loop
> should run as long as the value of level is less than the number of
> total levels. In the loop, you should do the following:
>
> Tell the player what level they are on. Depending on which level the
> player is on, the correct playLevel function should run. For example,
> if level is 2, then the playLevel2() function should execute. Increase
> the value of the level variable.

### What I tried:

```
function main() {
  //create level variable - start on level 1
  let level = 1;

  // create game loop that cycles through levels here

  while (level < NUM_LEVELS) {
    playLevel1();
    level++;
    playLevel2();
    level++;
    playLevel3();
    level++;
  }
}

//create playLevel1 function
function playLevel1() {
  console.log(
    "You are on level 1! You must escape the jungle before wild animals are unleashed! First lets escape this maze."
  );
}

//create playLevel2 function
function playLevel2() {
  console.log(
    "Good job escaping that maze! Now we must make it down this steep cliff."
  );
}

//create playLevel 3 function

function playLevel3() {
  console.log(
    "Finally, we must find the nearby village. Once that is complete, we will be safe."
  );
}

main();
```

Comment: Please add both task description and your code as text

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please [do not post image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). 
Also be more specific about your question. We can't have to read your statement (that is not a question, that is an assignment, and that is not what this site is for). And as written, your question (how to write while loop) is too vague. Plus, apparently you know how to write a while loop, since this is the only thing you already have.

Comment: sorry for being vague and using a screenshot, im new to the website and unsure of how to solve my problem. Thank you for taking the time to give me any help at all

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array (or an object) with `playLevel*` functions like this:

```
const levels = [playLevel1, playLevel2, playLevel2]
```

And then changed your while loop to this:

```
while (level < levels.length) {
  levels[level]();
  level++;
}
```

```js
function main() {
  //create level variable - start on level 1
  let level = 0;

  const levels = [playLevel1, playLevel2, playLevel2]

  // create game loop that cycles through levels here
  while (level < levels.length) {
    levels[level]();
    level++;
  }
}

//create playLevel1 function
function playLevel1() {
  console.log(
    "You are on level 1! You must escape the jungle before wild animals are unleashed! First lets escape this maze."
  );
}

//create playLevel2 function
function playLevel2() {
  console.log(
    "Good job escaping that maze! Now we must make it down this steep cliff."
  );
}

//create playLevel 3 function

function playLevel3() {
  console.log(
    "Finally, we must find the nearby village. Once that is complete, we will be safe."
  );
}

main();
```